# findViewById is null, am I not in the right View?

Tags: android

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    public void OnClickSendButton(View view) {
        EditText editTxt = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.MessageEditText);
        CharSequence toastText = editTxt.getText().toString();
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.example.faridahamat.androidlayout.MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/MessageEditText"/>
    <Button
        android:onClick="OnClickSendButton"/>
<GridLayout/>
```

I already called the `setContentView` to use the `activity_main.xml`, so why am I still not able to get the `MessageEditText`'s content? If `MainActivity` already uses the `activity_main.xml` as its layout, shouldn't I be able to get whatever that is inside that layout by calling Views that are inside?

I'm newbie, so my understanding of `Activity`/`View` might be wrong, please explain.

Comment: `view.findViewById` would be searching the view you clicked. Simply `findViewById` is the content view

Comment: why aren't you calling `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);` ?

Comment: @SantiagoHernández I removed unnecessary codes before I write here, of course :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you aren't.  The view returned in an `onClick` is the view that was clicked not the root view.

Generally its considered a good practice to use `findById` to find all the views you'll need in `onCreate`, so you don't need to do repeated N time walks of possibly complex hierarchies.

Comment: I picked this as correct answer, although the answer by cricket_007 below showed why I did it wrongly - via the codes. Thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
EditText editTxt = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.MessageEditText);
```

to

```
EditText editTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.MessageEditText);
```

The `View` you used it the button, you should look for `R.id.MessageEditText` in `R.layout.activity_main`, not in the button

Answer (score 1):

The `View` in the function `onClickSend` is the view of that button, not the view of the layout you're using for your `Activity`. So you're actually trying to find the `EditText` inside the `Button` view which is not right.

So `findViewById` should look like this.

```
EditText editTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.MessageEditText);
```

Its a good practice to get all the view references inside `onCreate` function to use them later wherever you want them to use. So like @AugustoCarmo said, get all the view references after you call the `setContentView` in your `onCreate` function.

And another thing is to setting the layout reference IDs properly. The ID of your `EditText` should look like `R.id.message_edit_text` instead of `R.id.MessageEditText`. This is conventional for layout reference id naming.

Comment: I comes from C# background, that naming conventional is a habit... :P

Answer (score 0):

A good practice is to get the reference of the views in `onCreate`

This will solve your problem:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText mMessageEditText;
    private Button mButtonView;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mMessageEditText = findViewById(R.id.MessageEditText);
        // you did not set an id to the button view
        // mButtonView = findViewById(BUTTON_VIEW_ID);
    }
    public void OnClickSendButton(View view) {
        CharSequence toastText = mMessageEditText.getText().toString();
    }
}
```